# Python django читать список снизу

Tags: python, django, for

Нужно читать список с низу, но я не пойму, как это реализовать тут:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contact.unique }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.pub_date }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

как сделать что-то типа?

```
{% for contact in range(len(contacts),-1,-1) %}
```

Хочу сделать это, чтобы брались из базы сначала новые записи, так как они добавляются в конец. Может кто-то подскажет другое решение?

Comment: Переверните список в представлении: `li.reverse()`. Или добавьте к модели поле `date` и фильтруйте по `-date`.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for). находим раздел со встроенными фильтрами и видим:

```
{% for obj in list reversed %}
```

В вашем случае:

```
{% for contact in contacts reversed %}
```